# What is the difference between Servlet response methods addHeader and setHeader?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

Can I use `setHeader` to set an new header?
Or Do I need to `addHeader` first, then use `setHeader` method?

Comment: Just beware addHeader of a Header that already exists, adds another Header, it does not append the new value to an existing Header.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The documentation says that you can add multiple values to a particular header using the `addHeader` method, whereas an initial value would be overwritten if you use the `setHeader` method.

In both cases a non-existent header would be created.

Answer (score 17):

[Javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) are your friend:

```
void addHeader(String name, String value)
```

> Adds a response header with the given name and value. 
>       This method allows response headers to have multiple values.

```
void setHeader(String name, String value)
```

> Sets a response header with the given name and value. If the header had already been set,
>       the new value overwrites the previous one. The containsHeader method can be used to test
>       for the presence of a header before setting its value.

Answer (score 7):

Both `setHeader()` and `addHeader()` will add a header and value to the response if the header is not already in the response. The difference between set and add shows up when the header is there. In that case: `setHeader()` overwrites the existing value, whereas `addHeader()` adds an additional value.

Comment: I like this answer the best.